# Python: How to separate list based on numerical values and strings from a given list

Tags: python

Consider I have a list like

```
listed = [1, 't', 'ret', 89, 95, 'man65', 67, 'rr']
```

Now  I need to write a script which will be like 2 lists; one `stringList` and `numberList` where,

```
stringList = ['t', 'ret', 'man65', 'rr']
numberList = [1, 89, 95, 67]
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far

Comment: @wahwahwah: I was going to say that, but then the answers started pouring in. So it's probably a little late now to ask for an MCVE.  :)

Comment: @PM2Ring everyone wants to be the fastest gun in the West!

Answer (score 6):

The standard way to check what kind of object you have is by
using the [isinstance(object, classinfo)](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance) function. Using `isinstance(...)` is preferred over [type(object)](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#type) because `type(...)` returns the exact type of an object, and does not account for sub-classes when checking types (this is significant in more complex scenarios).

You can check if you have a number (`int`, `float`, etc.) by comparing each class individually or with [numbers.Number](https://docs.python.org/library/numbers.html#numbers.Number):

```
# Check for any type of number in Python 2 or 3.
import numbers
isinstance(value, numbers.Number)

# Check for floating-point number in Python 2 or 3.
isinstance(value, float)

# Check for integers in Python 3.
isinstance(value, int)

# Check for integers in Python 2.
isinstance(value, (int, long))
```

You can check if you have a string (`str`, `bytes`, etc.) by comparing with the individual classes which vary depending on whether you're using Python 2 or 3:

```
# Check for unicode string in Python 3.
isinstance(value, str)

# Check for binary string in Python 3.
isinstance(value, bytes)

# Check for any type of string in Python 3.
isinstance(value, (str, bytes))

# Check for unicode string in Python 2.
isinstance(value, unicode)

# Check for binary string in Python 2.
isinstance(value, str)

# Check for any type of string in Python 2.
isinstance(value, basestring)
```

So, putting that all together you'd have:

```
import numbers

stringList = []
numberList = []
for value in mixedList:
    if isinstance(value, str):
        stringList.append(value)
    elif isinstance(value, numbers.Number):
        numberList.append(value)
```

Comment: note in Python 2 you should use `basestring` instead of `str` ...and in Py 3 I think you should use a tuple of `(str, bytes)` http://www.rfk.id.au/blog/entry/preparing-pyenchant-for-python-3/

Answer (score 2):

```
numbers, strings = both = [], []
for x in listed:
    both[isinstance(x, str)].append(x)
```

An alternative as an answer to Ajay's challenge in the comments to do it with just one list comprehension (note: this is a bad solution):

```
strings = [listed.pop(i) for i, x in list(enumerate(listed))[::-1] if isinstance(x, str)][::-1]
numbers = listed
```

Another:

```
numbers, strings = [[x for x in listed if isinstance(x, t)] for t in (int, str)]
```

Yet another, with the advantage of reading `listed` only once (inspired by PM 2Ring):

```
numbers, strings = [[x for x in l if isinstance(x, t)]
                    for l, t in zip(itertools.tee(listed), (int, str))]
```

Comment: Cute, but potentially confusing. :)

Comment: Hey @Stefan is it possible with list comprehension.I mean iterating only once

Comment: @Ajay Depends on what you mean. You could do `[both[isinstance(x, str)].append(x) for x in listed]`, of course :-P

Comment: but the immediate output is None,None,None...although numbers and strings will be populated

Comment: @Ajay: Exactly. Note the smilie on Stefan's comment: that code is intentionally silly.

Comment: @Ajay What 2Ring said. I gave a technically correct solution, but it's silly. I don't think it's possible what you have in mind, since one list comprehension gives you one list, and we want two.

Comment: [[i][j]] something like that

Comment: @Ajay I thought about something like that, but didn't get far. I added mine to my answer now, have a look.

Comment: @PM2Ring It's less silly than the one I added to my answer now, though.

Comment: i thought of pop too ...but dropped that idea

Comment: plus 1 for the second answer...but you come up with complicated solutions which need some serious thinking

Comment: @Ajay I don't find my first solution complicated. Also, thinking is good :-)

Comment: @StefanPochmann: No, the first solution is fine, but it'd be a little more readable IMHO if its first line was split into two. But if you want to see an alternative silly list comp, pop over to sopython chat. :)

Comment: @Ajay I added two more versions, using the [[][]] idea. The latter only goes through `listed` once.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in [type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) function to test each element in the list, and append it to a list based in its type.

```
numberList = []
stringList = []

for x in listed:
    if type(x) == int: numberList.append(x)
    else: stringList.append(x)
```

Comment: Using `isinstance()` is perferred over checking with `type()` because `isinstance()` can handle subclasses while `type()` checks the exact type.

Comment: @cpburnz True but in the OP's example he only has ints and strings. But I will note isinstance for the future, as I did not know about isinstance.

Comment: For further info on `isinstance()` vs type`()` please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/differences-between-isinstance-and-type-in-python

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks i'll have a look

Answer (score 1):

```
In [16]: sl=[i for i in a if isinstance(i,str)]

In [17]: nl=[i for i in a if isinstance(i,int)]

In [18]: sl
Out[18]: ['t', 'ret', 'man65', 'rr']

In [19]: nl
Out[19]: [1, 89, 95, 67]
```

Comment: One can use filter as well - but this one is faster and hence a preferred one

Answer (score 1):

Generic solution: grouping by **exact** object type.

```
multityped_objects = [1, 't', 'ret', 89, 95, 'man65', 67, 'rr', 12.8]
grouped = {}
for o in multityped_objects:
    try:
        grouped[type(o)].append(o)
    except KeyError:
        grouped[type(o)] = [o]

assert grouped[str] == ['t', 'ret', 'man65', 'rr']
assert grouped[int] == [1, 89, 95, 67]
assert grouped[float] == [12.8]
```